# How to use buttons with only glyphicons in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the proper markup for using a button with only a glyphicon in it in Twitter Bootstrap 3.0? If I use the following

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>
```

I get something like this:

[image]

**Update:**

I did a diff between the styles on mine and @Adrift's `<button>` element and got the following:

```
# -- is mine

--webkit-perspective-origin: 12px 8px;
+-webkit-perspective-origin: 12px 11px;

--webkit-transform-origin: 12px 8px;
+-webkit-transform-origin: 12px 11px;

-height: 16px;
+height: 22px;

-text-rendering: auto;
+text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/114/

Comment: I'm very confused... I have it all by itself with just the bootstrap css.

Comment: You're html is fine, it should be like that. It probably has to do with the way you put everything together. When you provide an example (jsfiddle or something) we might can help out.

Comment: could using the `file://` protocol affect it?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's the glypicon specifically.  Try setting the button contents to just a regular letter.  If it's still truncated, the problem is elsewhere.  When you view source, what's css rule is applying the height of 16 pixels on your button?

Comment: Work to me: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189310/twitter-bootstrap-wrong-heigth-of-button-with-icon-and-without-text/23197532#23197532?newreg=8decacbd0c004ef48e33013e5f192a31

Answer (score 42):

Try adding a non-breaking space after the icon span.

Like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;
</button>
```

Comment: I wouldn't ever imagined... Can you explain why is this?

Comment: @clapas it's because the span has to have content to show, otherwise it has no width and will collapse.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a little late but the correct answer is:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </button>
```

You have to add both glyphicon and glyphicon-{type} in the span class, a  not a  element. Good Luck

Comment: He already does this... Not sure how this is the "correct answer" to his question?

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola , it's slightly different: there are spaces around the <span> which is different from "nothing" which you get from newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same problem.
I found out that `<!DOCTYPE html>` was missing in index.html.
After I added this the button had right away the right size.
Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

(prior to version 3.0) 
Shouldn't it be ...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">
  <i class=" icon-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: Well, the Bootstrap documentation tells you to do it this way ... Also, glyphicon icons are called with the icon-???? in versions prior to 3.0. OP did't state what version they had.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on v.3.0. The `icon` prefix didn't fix anything.

Comment: What were you expecting to get? 3.0 is styled with a flat look.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use the glyphicon itself as a button

```
<div id="TrashButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
```

and then set an "onclick" method for it...

```
$("#TrashButton").on("click", function () {

    //do something

});
```

Comment: A potential problem is repeatedly clicking on this "button". The browser tries to highlight the area.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. In my case I always used them in conjunction with a Kendo window so I never came across that issue.

Comment: This is a good answer but you lose a lot of button functionality, such as you are unable to give a div the "disabled" property, etc. These can be emulated but it means extra overhead and unnecessary coding.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 
`<span role="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-lg" onclick="yourFunction()"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 5, using Bootstrap Icons this is the way to go:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
  <i class="bi bi-telephone-plus"></i>
</button>
```