# Twitter bootstrap: Wrong heigth of button with icon and without text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are two buttons on simple html page with attached twitter-bootstrap 2/3: with and without text. 
If I open it, button without text has wrong **smaller height** (See screenshot below). 
[image: Screenshot]

**How comes it?** Same situation repeats in IE 9\10. But if run in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27m9V/), all is fine. Even if i add a button in manualy via developer toolbar in some page with TB in internet all is ok.

P.S.: same thing with bootstrap 2...

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help you if you can't even replicate it yourself.  Do you have any styles in your own stylesheet, or is it solely bootstrap?

Comment: That's just the point, there is no other styles but bootstrap.

Comment: It doesn't work in all files created by me, whether it contains  php/js code or not. If i cut jsfiidle page via developer toolbar to my example - all works, but if create new html file - it fails..

Comment: Same thing happens with both "button" and  "a" tags. And I cant find any difference between jsfiddle/bootstap official pages and mine

Comment: It seems i've found the cause: it's "<!DOCTYPE html>" first string. If it doesn't exists ot it has html 4 description ("PUBLIC etc") this error occurs...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cause is `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` first string. It must be set as writter above for html 5. 
If it doesn't exists or it has html 4 description ("PUBLIC etc") this error occurs.

Comment: I had this problem, and your answer is solution.

Answer (score 2):

The font is different from Arial to Glyphicons (the font used for icons) this causes the difference.
To fix this, you may add a space (`&nbsp;`) to your button, after the `span`, to get the expected height, or you may fix it be increasing the `font-size` for the button.

**Edit:**
You also may increase `line-height` to fix this with adding anything

Comment: But what is the cause in bootsrap 2, where icons are images, not fonts?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap 2 icons were spite image

Comment: Try to specify `line-height` without adding space.. it should work

Comment: In Bt2 buttons has only 3 sizes and line-height helps. But in Bt3 buttons get size of current text, including headers. So you have to define to many styles...